# Fastest way to read large collection of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to store a large collection of small objects (chord diagrams) that will not change. It is a javascript project.
I have two questions:

1. how should I store these objects? As json, as text,... ?
2. what's the fastest way to find a specific item?

I search the item by it's key + type + "/" + bass:
Example: I get Am7/C# and I need to find the corresponding diagram. The key would be the file.

For now it's using only one file and search it with regex:

```js
"{define: C frets x 3 2 0 1 0 fingers 0 3 2 0 1 0}",
"{define: C(add9) frets x 3 2 0 3 0 fingers 0 2 1 0 3 0}",
```

I will have 90 000 chords that I can split in 12 files (one for each key).
My object can look like this:

```js
{type="m" bass="" frets="x 3 1 0 1 3" fingers="0 3 1 0 2 4" variation="1"}
```

I read a bit about binary search but I don't know if this can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What criteria are you going to use for the search? Is it going to be based on single prop of the following `type` `bass` `frets` `fingers` `vairation` ,   or the search term will be matched aginst all fields.

Btw also search over `90 000` entries of this size (the ones from the example) should not cause any performance issues

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. I need to find the chord by key + type + "/" + bass

Comment: In my opinion the storage format does not really matter, it should be of a kind which provides you with the most comfort of editing it. A secondary process can always transform this into JSON which might be the preferred format/way of loading such data. And as of the search, one might think of building from a list of diagram entries a key based store for fastening up the search, but only if the plain filtering of 90.000(plus) items is a highly repetitive tasks that somehow takes noticeably long or does slow down the UI after a while by running all the time.

Comment: And which kind of search should I use? I don't think regex is the best approach here

Comment: Start with the two most obvious approaches either [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing an array of 90.000(plus) chord items. Or having a `key` based map/index with each key storing its related chord item list (and start filtering from there).